# How to disable EditText's ability to recive copied text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

My quetion is simple and its exactly the same as in the Title.

How can i disable EditText's ability to recive copied text from elsewhere?
I mean when i long press the EditText, a box appears and i can choose to paste the text that i copied elsewhere. I just want to disable this feature.

What ways can i do it?

I tryed these but none of them worked for me:

```
myEditText.setClickable(false);
myEditText.setFocusable(false);
```

I also tryed .setEnabled(false) but that will disable the entire EditText, not the best solution becuse it becomes grey.

My app works with numbers and i dont want anything else character in my EditText.

Comment: Adam see this maybe helpful [How to disable copy/paste in EditText ](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2369a1ef917c7066)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the clipboard. You can find more information about that [`here`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html)

Comment: oh thats a broken link could you write it again please ?